Access a @pragma('vm:entry-point') method from a class which is inside a custom package into implementing app
Hi I am trying to create a package in flutter where this package is consuming a third party SDK and this SDK needs to register some handlers on the native code of the implementing app.
For example
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void registerThirdPartySDKMethod(){
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    ThirdPartySDK.setUp(SomeHandler());
}

This is the method which is inside my package under lin/src/presentation/exposed.dart file. I am trying to register this from implementing app native android code using below in MainApplication.kt class
val dartLibrary =
        "package:custom_sdk/src/presentation/exposed.dart"

SomeLibrary.initializeListener(this, dartLibrary, "registerThirdPartySDKMethod")

I am getting error that
[ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(117)] Dart Error: Dart_LookupLibrary: library 'package:custom_sdk/src/presentation/exposed.dart' not found.

My project structure is like below
-custom_sdk
 -example
   -sample_app
     -android
       -kotlin
         -MainApplication.kt
 -lib
   -src
     -presentation
     -exposed.dart

